# Improve select query on a physical table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with 184,970 rows and 9 columns; 6 of them are flags with values of 0 or 1 only.

When I run a simple select query

```
select * 
from table
```

it takes 17 seconds.

I haven't' created any indexes. Which column should I create an index on, if any? Because I'm retrieving all columns

Do you have any idea how can I improve the performance?

Comment: Don't select the whole table? That's a h*ck of a lot of rows to transfer over the network

Comment: I agree but we need all this data and I couldn't find another solution to it

Comment: Consider sharing the query plan using [https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). As @Charlieface already pointed out, transfering all data over the network is also time consuming. You can see this by turning on client statistics in SSMS (Shift + Alt + s)

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Do you have any idea or alternative for returning all of it at once?

Comment: What is a "simple select"? What is the query you're actually running? *Also, tables don't have "records", they have **rows** and columns.*

Comment: Is "a simple select query" equal to `SELECT * FROM table`. If so, why do you do this vague statement "a simple select query".. because some consider `SELECT * FROM table WHERE monday = yesterday` also a simple select query....

Comment: @Luuk  Question is updated. Apologize for the confusion

Comment: If you REALLY need ALL the data, then the first comment applies to your situation.

Comment: @Luuk But first comment says don't select all table !

Comment: If you **really** must get **all rows and all columns** - then no index will help you, since the whole table needs to be read anyway. An index will **only** help if you limit the number of columns being returned, and add a suitable `WHERE` clause to limit the rows being returned - in such a case, a proper index *could* help, possibly

Comment: What is the client going to do with 184,970 rows at once?

Comment: @AndrewSayer They need this data to be loaded in the local database of the android application

Comment: There is almost NO WAY to improve the performance of a query you posted. If your table truly has no index (including no primary key) then it is a heap. Fragmentation might be an issue and you can find suggestions for defragmenting a heap.

Comment: 9 columns; 6 of them are flags. What are the other three? How wide are they? What is running the SELECT? In what context are you seeing the 17 seconds? Is there some middle layer between the database and the Android app?

Comment: How long is it currently taking? How long does it need to take? Are you running the query frequently or just the once? What driver are you using to connect to the DB? How much time is associated with the network latency - if you increased the fetch size would that help much? How much time does it take for SQL Server to scan your table - would it be improved by compression?

Answer (score 3):

The database really has no choice on how to execute this query:

```
select * 
from table
```

It needs to scan all the data and return it.  If you need all the data in the table, then nothing is faster than a full table scan.

How can you improve performance?  Here are some ideas:

- Select fewer columns.  Fewer columns means less data being passed out of the database.  That should improve performance.
- Select fewer rows.  A `where` clause means less data *and* many `where` clauses can be optimized using indexes.
- Improve the network connectivity between the database and the application.
- Upgrade the hardware or other optimize the server where the database is running.

That said, I would question why you need to dump the entire table into an application.  That is not usually how databases are used.

This assumes that the "table" is really a table.  If it is a view, then all bets are off.  You may have an ability to use indexes or other methods to optimize the code in the view.

Comment: Actually I have a stored procedure which do some calculations and joining tables and it returns a table. The result of this stored procedure is being inserted in that table I have in my question. This sp runs 3 times a day and once it successfully returns a result the old data in the table is deleted and the new one is being inserted.And that result needs to be available in the client local db  to avoid hitting the server many times and in case they don't have internet connection which is mostly the case

Comment: @Rahul . . . Caching the data locally is actually a good reason to download the entire table.  Of course, you might find that users are using stale data -- and that could be a business issue.  The solution is to improve internet connectivity.  You *might* find it faster to export the table as a file on a common server and then load the file into a table on the application side.  Files are easier to compress, for instance, than query results.

Comment: Compressing the data might be helpful in the matter of the storage and memory of client side but it's not my concern now.I also think the compressing and then decompress will increase the time so I want to avoid it

Comment: @rahul . . . Compressing and uncompressing might actually be faster than reading the uncompressed data.

Comment: Can you explain to me how it would be faster. it's an additional step so I automatically assumed it will take more time.

Comment: @Rahul . . . I remember testing such things so long ago that I don't care to admit when.  Since then both disks and processors have become faster -- but I think processors have become more faster.  And it is processor speed that dominates uncompression.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the data in any table, the only improivement is to limit the data types.  For example when you have a 0/1 flag, ensure this is stored as a bit not an int or tiny int etc.

Indexing won't be of any use as you are not joining or filtering the results in any way.

There are some possibilities around hardware changes where reads are being made from the disk I/O, i.e. physical reads as opposed to logical reads.  Also network transmition speeds if your query is run on a different machine to your server, but you are getting into really deep water here.

May be worth running the query with your time and i/o stats turned on to see if query is a physical read or logical read.  Also try running the query locally on the server to remove possible network issues (if on seperate machines) and add your findings to the original question.

Other than that, a "basic" select * from table doesn't leave you with many options.

Answer (score 0):

Those 3 columns that aren't bits.  Are any of them huge? varbinary(max) for example?  If so, I don't think there's much you can do besides select less rows.

Otherwise, this sounds like a hardware or network connectivity issue to me.  I have a larger, non-indexed table.  And SELECT * FROM Table returns 185,000 rows in 1 second.

If the database isn't hosted on your local machine.  Is it possible to log directly into the server and see if it's still slow?  You could confirm or rule out internet speed as the issue.

I would also check if the memory or CPU is being taxed.  Reboot the server. Maybe increase the available memory SQL Server is using.  Things like that.  Newer versions of SQL server on a half-way decent machine should be able to spit out 185,000 bit fields like nothing.

Comment: No they're not huge. Actually all of them are of type intt except one of type bigInt. If I switched the flags columns to bit will make a difference? either way the data will be stored as 0 or 1

Comment: In that case, it sounds like a SQL Server/Windows/Hardware/Internet issue to me.  And not a query issue or a database design issue.  Sorry I can't help more.